# Find the salary of each employee department wise

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following 3 tables
Emp(eid: integer, ename: string, age: integer, salary: numeric) Works(eid: integer, did: integer, pct_time: integer)
Dept(did: integer, dname: string, budget: numeric, managerid: integer)

and I want to write oracle sql query to Find salary of each employee department wise

Comment: provide sample data and desired output , plus show us your try

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select d.dname, e.ename, w.pct_time * e.salary
from emp as e
inner join works as w using (eid)
inner join dept as d using (did)
     order by w.did
```